# Aggregations in Application Insights analytics treated as scalars

Tags: azure-application-insights

I have this query in application insights analytics

```
let total = exceptions 
| where timestamp >= ago(7d)
| where problemId contains "Microsoft.ServiceBus"
| summarize sum(itemCount);

let nullContext = exceptions 
| where timestamp >= ago(7d) 
| where problemId contains "Microsoft.ServiceBus" 
| where customDimensions.["SpecificTelemetry.Message"] == "HttpContext.Current is null" 
| summarize sum(itemCount); 

let result = iff(total == nullContext, "same", "different");
result
```

but I get this error

> Invalid relational operator

I am surprised as yesterday with the same code (as far as I remember) I was getting a different error saying that both sides of the check would need to be scalar but my understanding was that the aggregation even if it displays a value (under sum_countItem) it's not a scalar. But couldn't find a way to transform it or now to get rid of this work.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Couple of issues.
First - the Invalid relational operator is probably due to the empty lines between your let statements. AI Analytics allows you to write several queries in the same window, and uses empty lines to separate those. So in order to run all the statements as a single query you need to eliminate the empty lines.

Regarding the error of "Left and right side of the relational operator must be scalars" - the result of the "summarize" operator is a table and not scalar. It can contain a single line/column or multiple of those (think of what happens if you add a "by" clause to the summarize).
To achieve what you want to do you might want to use a single query as follows:

```
exceptions 
| where timestamp >= ago(7d)
| where problemId contains "Microsoft.ServiceBus"
| extend nullContext = customDimensions.["SpecificTelemetry.Message"] == "HttpContext.Current is null"
| summarize sum(itemCount) by nullContext
```